# Use Amazon SNS to send SMS messages using PHP AWS SDK v3.199.0?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send an SMS with the latest version of the Aws SDK, in my project I do not use any type of PHP frameworks.

I don't want to send mass notifications to a bunch of phone numbers subscribed to a specific topic when an action happens, I want to send a notification to a specific phone number when an action happens.

I'm testing with this code that the AWS documentation provides but it doesn't work:

```
require_once('../aws/aws-autoloader.php');

use Aws\Sns\SnsClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

$SnSclient = new SnsClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-03-31'
]);

$message = 'YOUR_MESSAGE';
$phone = 'PHONE_NUMBER';

$result = $SnSclient->publish([
    'Message' => $message,
    'PhoneNumber' => $phone,
]);

var_dump($result);
```

Right in the `publish` part it throws me an `Error 500`

```
$result = $SnSclient->publish([
    'Message' => $message,
    'PhoneNumber' => $phone,
]);
```

What should I do? I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: You should check your server logs, a 500 error is not helpful and is not the error you receive from AWS but what your server then responds to its client with because it encountered some exception from AWS. How are your AWS credentials configured, do those credentials allow SNS notification publishing?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. It is the first time that I am using this Aws service so I have no idea where I should put the credentials. Could you guide me? Thanks!

Comment: No, cannot guide you since I never used PHP + AWS but you simply need to follow some tutorials.